# Location of Terme di Nikà - Pantelleria

Tags: italy, identify-this, islands, locate-this, sicily

I found interesting spot to visit on Pantelleria island in Italy - Terme di Nikà, bur I can't find exact location on goggle map. Can someone help?

Edit: here is a spot I am looking for:

[image: Terme di Nikà]

[link on the website](http://www.visitpantelleria.com/portfolio/cala-nika/)

Answer (score 1):

On google maps there is [Discesa a mare nikà](https://www.google.it/maps/place/discesa+a+mare+nik%C3%A0/@36.7447965,11.9864264,15z) which matches up the location given in this [page](http://www.viverepantelleria.it/isola-di-pantelleria/le-localita).

> Nikà è la località situata sul tratto costiero sud-occidentale
>   dell'Isola di Pantelleria

Roughly, Nikà is the locality situated on the South West coast of Pantelleria.

Here's a picture of the sign leading down to the terme:
[image]

Comment: This is the place we found. It is the closest point you can reach with a car. The place I'm looking for is the hot water in the see. According to some websites it should be 70 degrees C.

Comment: @mligor Did you see the sign and follow it? It should lead to the location, and if tripadvisor is to believed, it's likely there will be many boats there with swimmers too

Comment: Yes. I want down to the water, but can't find any hot spot. And there are no swimmers at this time of the year. I think during the season you can go with the boat until the right spot. Now we have to take some rocky road - but which one?

Comment: @mligor There are 32 photos here: https://www.tripadvisor.it/Attraction_Review-g194847-d10488171-Reviews-Terme_di_Nika-Pantelleria_Islands_of_Sicily_Sicily.html#photos

Comment: yes. I know that. I found Terme de Nika on TripAdvisor. Today I spent whole day looking for the that spot. Sea is not so easy to reach at that point and I was not able to identify nothing from given photos.  And there is nobody to ask - I will try to find some locals tomorrow who can point me to the right direction.

Comment: @mligor Good luck tomorrow!